Difference in temperature between two CPUs with the same usage
Let's say we have two Intel Core CPUs,
A i5-1135G7 (4 cores / 8 threads, 28 Watt) and
a i7-1360P (12 cores / 16 threads, 28 Watt) (hopefully this comparison is correct enough).
These CPUs have the same wattage but the first one is less power than the second one (link to CPUs comparison). I'm interested in heating of these two CPUs with the same usage. Let's say we have one core loaded on 50%. Do I get right that i7-1360P wouldn't be heating so much like i5-1135G7 and wouldn't be heating at whole because of its performance?

The core i7 will have better performance/watt. The biggest reason for this is the process node its manufactured on (7nm vs 10nm). Difference in temperature however depends on more factors, like what code exactly you are running, which cooling solutions are used, the environment, ...

@Silbee, ok, we've figured out that Core i7 would be more effective than Core i5, so Core i5 will be hotter than Core i7 in executing the same tasks, right? But on another hand, Core i7 has 7 nm process, so the single core is tinier and will be hotter with the same power dissipation, did I get right?

It really is hard to say unfortunately. I understand your reasoning because physics, ... But its not as straight forward. Your task might end faster on the i7, causing it to run less long and not get as hot for example. Your task might be cache hungry, with the i7 having more cache, it might get hotter (caches take up ALOT of die space compared to a single core). Then there's all kinds of tech in these CPU's that do so much power management you have no control over, all of which might influence the final result.

Taking all that into account i would just take the following: since both are 28W parts, they will both yield similar temperatures for similar tasks. However the i7 will have better watt/performance making it able to finish a task faster. Unless the task is 24/7 the same, the i7 will have more idle time and in the overall sense have a lower overall temperature.

You cannot apply this simple arithmetic to modern CPUs.
To begin, these CPUs are two generations apart, and therefore built with different silicon technology, so the later is more power efficient just at the transistor level.
But most importantly, all modern CPU platforms include a Power Management system of tremendous complexity. Modern PMU (Power Management Units) control all aspects of CPU running, starting with dynamic clock control, voltage control, power/clock gating, load monitoring and power/temperature monitoring. Algorithms for the control are under continuous improvements from one generation to another, like tuning power policies (number of P-states) etc., so it is impossible to predict anything with simple arithmetic.
You can take a look at this white paper of Intel to appreciate the complexity of this subsystem.
